# Bluemix Personality Insights code 500

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Ive installed the sample directly into bluemix/devops services using the automatic install button with no changes. I click on "Analyze my Twitter Personality" and it takes me to this url
http://personality-insights-nodejs-sgarforthjazz-1321.mybluemix.net/auth/twitter?
which displays this output
{"code":500,"error":{}}

Answer (score 2):

To use the "Analyze my Twitter Personality" feature you will need to setup twitter application credentials in the `credentials.json` file, at the root of the project.

For this, you need to create a new Twitter Application [here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new) and copy both Consumer Key (API Key) and Consumer Secret (API Secret) into the `credentials.json` file, into `twitter.application.consumer_key` and `twitter.application.consumer_secret` fields respectively.

You can read more about this in [demo's README.md](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs#setting-up-twitter-application)

Comment: Hi Ary, I've done this already but I was unable to get it working.  Do I need to put in my access token and secret somewhere as well?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. Yes, you will need to add your Personality Insights service's username and password on `credentials.json`.